# How to assign a variable to a single host from host_var file

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible roles, and my host file looks like this:

```
[labmx]
lab-mx
```

The lab-mx.yml file looks like this:

```
routers: 
  - 10.10.10.15
  - 10.10.10.16
```

When the Playbook runs I want to assign a specific variable to the first router in the list. Is there a way to do that?

I also have a labmx.yml group_var file which has a bunch of vars that get associated to both routers in the list.

How can I assign a single variable to 10.10.10.15 which does not get applied to 10.10.10.16?

Comment: Add the routers to your inventory and create a host_vars file for each of them with the corresponding variables

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official documentation - [Assigning variables to one/specific machine(s)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#adding-variables-to-inventory).

In your case you can easily assign variables in the hosts file **inline** like this.

**Note** - "Setting variables in the main inventory file is only a shorthand"

```
[labmx]
10.10.10.15 somevar=somevalue
10.10.10.16
```

You can also use the [host_vars file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) if there are too many variables as suggested in comments by @zeitounator.